# Utilizar mais de um valor para usar de parâmetro em uma função Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, query, oracle, pl-sql, oracle12c

Boa tarde, Estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso executar uma função que calcula o valor médio de um produto em uma data especifica.

*SELECT VERIF_VL_CUSTO_MEDIO(PRODUTO.CD_PRODUTO,
to_date('31/01/2021','dd/mm/yyyy'))
FROM PRODUTO;*

Porem eu preciso executar essa consulta, de modo que retorno os valores para o ultimo dia de cada Mês nos últimos 12 meses.

Tentei talvez criar uma estrutura de repetição, mas não obtive sucesso.

Agradeço a ajuda de todos

Answer (score 0):

```
    --sem testes todavia
    --criação de uma view
    --sequencia retroativa
    SELECT (LEVEL-1)*-1
    FROM   DUAL 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;
    
    --gerando datas nisto
    SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),(LEVEL-1)*-1) REFEF
    FROM   DUAL 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;
    
    --gerando datas ultimos dias
    SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),(LEVEL-1)*-1)) ULD_DIA_REFEF
    FROM   DUAL 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;
    
    --criando a view
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_VL_ULTIMAS_DATAS AS
    SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),(LEVEL-1)*-1) refer,
           LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),(LEVEL-1)*-1)) ULD_DIA_REFEF
    FROM   DUAL 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;

    --produto cartesiano proposital
   SELECT VERIF_VL_CUSTO_MEDIO(PRODUTO.CD_PRODUTO,
                               VUD.ULD_DIA_REFEF) CST_MED
   FROM PRODUTO P,V_VL_ULTIMAS_DATAS VUD
   WHERE NOME_PRODUTO = 'XPTO;
    
    
    --poderia generalizar o "12" fazendo um MONTHS_BETWEEN 
    --entre a data atual e a menos data de produtos o 
    --filtro seria aplicado na view

    --editei para retirar a function da view
    --o que pode ser feito é um "join" entre " produtos e 
    --esta view
```

Comment: é compilou, usei um material e uma data no filtro, só q ficou 30 minutos rodando e eu cancelei a consulta.
Tinha pensando em fazer um LOOP usando o campo de data, mas n sei como fazer isso no Oracle